# How to format a value to text in BI publisher

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I am trying to create a report in BI. I have created a data model using a sql script and the data type is string. I then created a report using this data model and the sample data is showing as 06185 as shown below.

[image: Sample Data]

But when i run the report the output is showing as 6185.0 with decimal places.

[image]

I have tried to change the format by double clicking the value. But I cant choose any format except none in the report designer. What I need is the values to be displayed same as the sample data.

Comment: Is the output going to Excel? Looks like its auto changing values like document number too.

Answer (score 1):

06185 is not a number - it's a string. As a number you will never have leading 0s. 6185 is a number.

So first of all you need to find out what your data is really supposed to be. "06185" = string. 6185 = integer. 6185.0 = double.

Comment: Exactly.  A ```TO_CHAR(06185)``` should fix this right up.

Comment: Having the same issue here  .nothing from the answers works . any luck ?

Answer (score 0):

To be quick simply add ' character next to the number character... Else excel will make your life difficult specially if you have bank account numbers...

```
SELECT   payees.supplier_site_id csupplier_site_id,
  payees.org_id c_org_id,
  payees.payee_party_id ,
  cbbv.bank_name,
   max(''''||to_char(ieb.bank_account_num)) as  bank_account_num   
FROM apps.iby_pmt_instr_uses_all instrument,
  apps.iby_account_owners owners,
  apps.iby_external_payees_all payees,
  apps.iby_ext_bank_accounts ieb,
   apps.ap_supplier_sites_all asa,
   apps.ap_suppliers asp,
  apps.ce_bank_branches_v cbbv
WHERE owners.primary_flag      = 'Y'
AND owners.ext_bank_account_id = ieb.ext_bank_account_id
AND owners.ext_bank_account_id = instrument.instrument_id
AND payees.ext_payee_id        = instrument.ext_pmt_party_id
AND payees.payee_party_id      = owners.account_owner_party_id
AND payees.supplier_site_id    = asa.vendor_site_id
AND asa.vendor_id              = asp.vendor_id  
and bank_party_id(+) = ieb.bank_id  
--AND cbbv.branch_party_id(+)    = ieb.branch_id
AND (
(INSTRUMENT.END_DATE IS NULL)
OR
( INSTRUMENT.END_DATE >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE) )  
) 
AND (
(IEB.END_DATE IS NULL)
OR
(IEB.END_DATE >= TO_DATE(SYSDATE))
)
 group by  payees.supplier_site_id  ,
  payees.org_id ,
  payees.payee_party_id ,
  cbbv.bank_name
```

Answer (score -1):

You may have to edit this with the desktop Microsoft Word add-in. There's limited capabilities with the Oracle BI Publisher Stand-alone running on the server.

You have 100% control if you're editing the template in Word. Unfortunately, there's limited export capability to export your existing template. Oracle BI publisher stand-alone will export an XML file, which to my knowledge is not visually editable in Word. There is an ability to import an RTF file which you created in Word, though. So Install the BI Publisher desktop/Word add-in. Make a new file, save as .rtf format, use the tool to import an example XML file, add a table, and continue editing as you need to. If you need help with this, there's plenty of documentation out there to get you started. Also, there's a Template Viewer application that's also installed that will let you process the XML sample/data file and rtf file into Excel, PDF, or whichever you prefer.